# Plugging holes in Top Plate wood?

Tags: wood, attic

So I was running Ethernet around the house, and there were a couple of places where the top plate holes were incorrect and I had to redrill (holes no bigger than a 3/4 an inch). I got everything drilled right and ran....however what should I plug the other couple of holes with? (Just to get them filled). I doubt it did much structural damage (since it's just a single hole), but I still feel like I should "fill" them with something?

Is there some sort of wood filler? Or something? I know I should use fire-retardant foam where the ethernet cables come through...but right now just concerned with the holes that are just open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code requires fire retardant foam in new construction nowadays. If you have an older home where that was not required, you could leave it or fill it with standard caulk, if you feel you must do something.

Comment: Isn’t fire retardant foam ONLY required in fire rated construction?

Comment: It is placed in in every penetration through every plate in every floor, and I believe in every hole in the studs of residential construction for a number of years now. In MD and also in WA. It is along the lines of fireblocking where a fire can travel from a vertical space to  horizontal.

Comment: In commercial, industrial, educational and multi-family (including condos), but not in single family residential. Fire wall, yes, but R302.13 says penetrations are permitted....including drainage pipes, ducts, wires, luminaries, etc. (Penetrations in blocking can be up to 80 square feet per floor, which allow for electrical boxes, etc. See R302.13, Exception 3.)

Comment: Good to know, I am going by what I see, and what the inspectors require, that I know of. It has been the case in MD for the time I lived there, until I moved to WA state, and seen the same thing here, all in single family homes. But I never have read it in the code book, only what I seen on the jobsites.